# Exponential notation for Galois group and egality

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, arithmetic, group-actions, group-presentation

Let $G$ a non abelian group of order 20 generated by two elements $\sigma$ and $\tau$ such that $G = \langle \sigma, \tau |\,\, \sigma^5 = \tau^4 = 1,\, \tau\sigma = \sigma^3\tau,\, \sigma\tau = \tau\sigma^2 \rangle$.

We have that $G$ acts on a group (H, .) by the following action, $\forall \,a \in H$ and $\forall\, \sigma_1, \sigma_2 \in G$,  we have $(a^{\sigma_1})^{\sigma_2} = a^{\sigma_2\sigma_1}$.

Let $H^+ = \{ a \in H \,|\, a^{\tau^2} = a^{\sigma}= a\}$, $H^- = \{ a \in H \,|\, a^{\tau^2} = a^{-1}\}$ and $H^{1-\sigma} = \{ a^{1-\sigma} \,|\, a \in H\}$ be a subgroups of $H$.

I am trying to prove that $(H^+)^{1-\sigma} \subset H^+$ and $(H^-)^{1-\sigma} \subset H^+$ in order to deduce that $H^{1-\sigma} \subset H^+$ because we have that $H = H^+ \times H^-$.

I proced as follows:

Let $a \in H^+$, since $(a^{1-\sigma})^{\tau^2}\,=\,a^{\tau^2-\tau^2\sigma}\,=\,a^{\tau^2-\sigma^4\tau^2}\,=\,(a^{\tau^2})^{1-\sigma^4}\,=\,a^{1-\sigma^4} = a^{1-\sigma}$ because $a^{\sigma^4} = a^{\sigma}$, then $(H^+)^{1-\sigma}\,\subset\, H^+$.

But a referee gave this comments:

"you write $(a^{1-\sigma})^{\tau^2}\,=\,a^{\tau^2-\tau^2\sigma}$. This
seems like you are thinking that $(a^{1-\sigma})^{\tau^2}\,=\,a^{\tau^2(1-\sigma)}$.
This is not the correct interpretation of the left-hand side.
To see the correct interpretation of the left-hand side, notice you are
wanting to show that $(H^+)^{1-\sigma} \subset H^+$. Thus you want to show that $\tau^2$ acts trivially on $(H^+)^{1-\sigma}$. You can see what the correct interpretation of the left-hand side has to be from this."

I can't understand where is the mistake in my reasoning, and what is the correct interpretation of the left-hand side.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by "$1-\sigma$" - since you're writing your group operation multiplicatively (which is correct, as your group is nonabelian), what exactly does subtraction mean here? Do you mean $\sigma^{-1}$, that is, the inverse of $\sigma$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Presumably $a^{1-\sigma}:=a(a^\sigma)^{-1}$. Although, OP, doesn't that make $(H^+)^{1-\sigma}$ trivial, since your definition of $H^+$ implies all its elements are fixed by $\sigma$? (Also I assume your $X$s should be $H$s when defining $H^{\pm}$s.)

Comment: There is something perverse (or perhaps sinister?) in making a left action and the using right exponential notation. Having to switch the order makes a complete hash of the benefit of using that notation in the first place. One should either define a right action, or use ${}^{\sigma}a$.

Comment: the notation $a^{1-\sigma}$ means $a^{1-\sigma} = a(a^\sigma)^{-1}$. I see that $(H^+)^{1-\sigma}$ is trivial, But my question is about the interpretation of $(a^{1-\sigma})^{\tau^2}$, the referee said that $(a^{1-\sigma})^{\tau^2} = a^{\tau^2-\tau^2\sigma} $ is incorrect. Can we proced as follows : $(a^{1-\sigma})^{\tau^2} = a^{\tau^2}((a^\sigma)^{-1})^{\tau^2}  = a^{\tau^2}((a^{-1})^{\sigma})^{\tau^2}=.......$